# как загрузиться с другой системы (Windows)

Tags: windows, bios, загрузчик

И так, у меня есть 2 системы, на диске 1 и диске 2.
Система 1 установлена с флешки на диск 1 и она загружается по умолчанию, а система 2 установлена с помощью WinNTSetup на диск 2 и нет возможности с неё загрузиться, даже если она успешно установлена и работать будет, у неё есть bootmgr. Ни Виндовс ни БИОС не видят эту систему 2. Я пробовал сделать параметр в БИОС, чтобы открывался bootmgr системы 2, но БИОС игнорит этот параметр и загружает систему 1.
Что делать, чтобы загрузилась система 2?

Comment: Нихрена не понятно. Можно скрин обоих дисков из `Gparted Live`?